# Need a rotatable circle for Android application. Customized object or widget?

Tags: android, widget, rotation

I need to create a circle that rotates and contains data for my application. Should I create a customized object for my application or should I make a in-application widget?

While on the topic, how do you refer to a widget within an application instead of a stand alone widget for the android desktop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a rotatable LinearLayout that you can put everything in it and you can rotate it by degree if you customize it. use rotate() method to rotate it and...

enjoy! ;)

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class RotateLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {

    private Matrix mForward = new Matrix();
    private Matrix mReverse = new Matrix();
    private float[] mTemp = new float[2];
    private float degree = 0;

    public RotateLinearLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public RotateLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        try {
            if (degree == 0) {
                super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
                return;
            }
            canvas.rotate(degree, getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);

            mForward = canvas.getMatrix();
            mForward.invert(mReverse);
            canvas.save();
            canvas.setMatrix(mForward); // This is the matrix we need to use for
                                        // proper positioning of touch events

            super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
            canvas.restore();
            invalidate();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (degree == 0) {
            return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
        }
        // final float[] temp = mTemp;
        // temp[0] = event.getX();
        // temp[1] = event.getY();
        // mReverse.mapPoints(temp);
        // event.setLocation(temp[0], temp[1]);
        event.setLocation(getWidth() - event.getX(), getHeight() - event.getY());
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }

    public void rotate() {
        if (degree == 0) {
            degree = 180;
        } else {
            degree = 0;
        }
    }

}
```

**Update:**

add this code to your xml layout and put your Views like ImageView or another LinearLayout in it :

```
<org.mabna.order.ui.RotateLinearLayout  android:id="@+id/llParent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >



<ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/myImage"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dip"
                        android:src="@drawable/main01" />

</org.mabna.order.ui.RotateLinearLayout>
```

in onCreate() method:

```
llParent = (RotateLinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.llParent);
```

in onClickListener of a button:

```
protected void btnRotate_onClick() {
        llParent.rotate();
    }
```

**Update2:**

You can use an animation for rotation before real rotation (`llParent.rotate();`). it needs an animation layout like rotate_dialog.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000" android:fromDegrees="-180" android:toDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%" android:fillAfter="true" />
```

and in your code:

```
protected void btnRotate_onClick() {
        // rotate 
        Animation rotateAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                R.anim.rotate_dialog);
        llParent.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
        llParent.rotate();
    }
```

Comment: thanks a lot! But i'm not sure how to use this code. What do I set in setContentView? How do I add objects (rotating circle) to this view? I assume this is a frame for making rotation possible. I'm used to seeing LinearLayout in xml so if it's in Java I'm not sure how to use it programmatically. How should I be using this view? Thanks, im a bit new here haha.

Comment: THanks man! If I can upvote you more than once i would. I'm getting some errors upon clicking the button. What's the behavior of this view? If I click the button the view will rotate 180 degrees? The error is when I call the rotate method of the RotateLInearLayout class, instance llparent.

Comment: what is your error? have you customized name space of `org.mabna.order.ui.RotateLinearLayout`

Comment: the previous error i had was from handling the click event incorrectly. I've fixed that so the button is responsive. But I still have an error when I call the rotate() method on llParent. findViewById(R.id.llParent) doesn't seem to be working as llParent is null.

Comment: some fact checking later, turns out I was calling findViewById before I setContentView

Comment: thanks! This a good code sample. So your code allows a 180 flip of everything within the LinearLayout. I was looking for more of a real time rotation, like a dial wheel. If you have suggestions that would be sweet.

Comment: Thank you so much for this.  The only additional thing I had to do was add a local Variable for the llparent since I was using the code in another method.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

There is a fairly easy way to make a rotating animation from a custom widget derived from the [`View`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) class.  After the view is created and placed in your layout, you can call `View.setAnimation(Animation)` or `View.startAnimation(Animation)`, supplying a [`RotateAnimation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/RotateAnimation.html) on the view to start it.  Here is an example of a rotation animation defined in xml, that can be loaded from your activity with `getResources().getAnimation(int)`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="float"
    android:toDegrees="float"
    android:pivotX="float"
    android:pivotY="float" />
```